# Is it possible to downgrade "Google Keep" app?

Tags: android, search, google-keep

The latest "Google Keep" app has a bug with Searching and I don't want to wait for Google to come out with a fix. So, I was wondering if I can get the "Google Keep" downgraded for the time being.

Is it possible to Downgrade? 
If yes, will I be able to downgrade without Rooting my Smart phone?
Also will I be able to get the older version from Google Play Store?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You should ask this question on the Android Enthusiasts sister site. https://android.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question and belongs on android.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

I could downgrade the app by getting the relevant version from AkpMirror.com and then install the same using adb without rooting my phone.

I also disabled auto update for the app.